# Where can I find the appropriate tax class ids in Magento database?

Tags: magento

When I create a product in Magento using the API, I need to supply a field that's called 'tax_class_id'. I want to find out, which id I need to supply for a VAT percentage, like 20% in Austria or 19% in Germany.

Where can I find those ids inside the database?

*Side note: I actually want to write an api extension that returns a list of percentage values along with their tax class. If someone has an easier idea how to do that, it'll be fine as well!*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have Firefox with Firebug, or similar inspect functionality as most nowadays browsers have, you can just inspect the tax class select field in any product and view the tax class id's in the html.

If you need to read them from the database, you can find them in the table called 'tax_class'.

Comment: Thank you. I've found the database table and I'm also a bit ashamed right now because I didn't see it before. I have actually used the table search feature of phpMyAdmin and had no doubts that it wouldn't find a table containing 'tax', however, it's unbelievable that the table search feature only searches using javascript in the current page(!). Because tax_class is actually in the second page, it wouldn't find that... thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can find it inside *tax_class* table.

```
SELECT * FROM tax_class
```

Comment: @Ricando, how to get programmatically as per magento standard?